# Dificuldade para acessar json

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Tenho o seguinte json:

```
            {
  "destination_addresses": [
    "Rua B, 1 - Coqueiro,Belém - PA, 66670-350, Belém - PA, 66670-350, Brasil"
  ],
  "origin_addresses": [
    "Pref. José Walter, Fortaleza - CE, 60810-670, Brasil"
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "elements": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "1.495 km",
            "value": 1495361
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "20 horas 33 minutos",
            "value": 74009
          },
          "status": "OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

minha dificuldade é básica eu sei, mas não estou conseguindo acessar os nós do json, quando eu tento

`data.destination_addresses` me retorna exatamente

`["Rua B, 1 - Coqueiro,Belém - PA, 66670-350, Belém - PA, 66670-350, Brasil"]`

e não apenas o valor.. `Rua B, 1 - Coqueiro,Belém - PA, 66670-350, Belém - PA, 66670-350, Brasil`

e também não consigo acessar por exemplo o `distance` ou `duration` ja tentei `data.rows.elements.distance` e `data.rows[0].elements.distance` porem também não consigo.. o que esta faltando para que eu possa acessar os nós?

obs. utilizo vuejs.

Comment: `data.destination_addresses` dá-te uma array, isso é util se quiseres dividir por linhas. É esse o caso? E o que é `data.rows.elements`? Em que HTML queres inserir dados daí?

Comment: Olá @Sergio `data.rows.elements` esto tentando imprimir esse nó no pagina tipo `{{data.rows.elements}} mas é undefined

Comment: Mas deves ter um `v-for` algures certo? Coloca o teu componente Vue para ficar mais claro.

Comment: @Sergio olha o que estou tentando fazer aqui https://jsfiddle.net/26utr8wd/

Comment: Não tive tempo ainda de ver. Amanhã vou dar uma olhada se ainda não tiveres resolvido o problema.

Comment: @Sergio gostaria sim amigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Editada: Complemento:
>
> Note que `Elements` é, também, um rray  de objetos ("distance" e "duration") e que esse array (`Elements`) está dentro de outro array que é `rows`, então para vc acessar um objeto de `Elements` vai ter que fazer uma iteração em `row` e em `Elements`, algo mais ou menos assim (python como inspiracao)

```
for row in data.rows:
    for element in row.elements:
       print (element.distance)
       #...
```

Quando vc acessa `data.destination_addresses` o retorno é exatamente o que o autor do json quis expressar, um array de strings, provavelmente alguns endereços devam ter mais de uma string (mais de um endereço).
Veja que `data.rows` é, também, uma matriz, entao vc teria que acessar assim:

```
drows = data.rows[0]
```

E então 'analisar' drows.

Answer (score 0):

Retificando o comentário de acordo com a observação abaixo, realmente não existe erro na array, a forma apresentada está correta, consegui acessar os dados da array `elements` sem maiores problemas, mas é necessário indicar o index dos objetos dentro da array `console.log(json.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value);`

```js
var json = {
  "destination_addresses":
    ["Rua B, 1 - Coqueiro,Belém - PA, 66670-350, Belém - PA, 66670-350, Brasil"],
  "origin_addresses":
    ["Pref. José Walter, Fortaleza - CE, 60810-670, Brasil"],
  "rows":[
    {"elements":
        [{
          "distance": {"text": "1.495 km", "value": 1495361},
          "duration": {"text": "20 horas 33 minutos", "value": 74009 },
          "status": "OK"
        }]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
console.log(json.rows[0]);
console.log(json.rows[0].elements[0]);
console.log(json.rows[0].elements[0].duration);
console.log(json.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value);
```

Comment: `Elements` é um array de objetos, com somente um elemento (no exemplo), esse elemento é um objeto que contem 2 'sub-objetos', `distance` e `duration`. A meu ver não tem erro.

Comment: Tem razão, interpretei como se ele quisesse colocar vários elementos dentro da array. Refiz meu teste consegui acessa-los.

Comment: Mas acredito que o problema que ele estava tendo de acessar os dados dos objetos continua, pois  como o objeto esta dentro da array `Elements` ele precisaria busca-los indicando o index da mesma forma que fez em `rows`. Em vez de `data.rows[0].elements.distance` seria `data.rows[0].elements[0].distance`. Correto?

Comment: Sem conhecer o contexto, continuo achando q o ideal seria que fizesse uma iteração em `elements`, para percorre todos os elelentos (esse nome deve ter sido intencional).